# Preserving HTML with Watson Document Conversion

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

We have Microsoft Word documents structured such that they generate quality Watson RaR JSON answer units using the Watson Document Conversation Service. However, any working links in the Word document are removed by the Doc Con service in the resulting JSON answer units which are just plane text.

Is there a way to configure the Doc Con service to preserve these links so that the link HTML appears in the resulting JSON answer units? If not, how do you suggest we proceed in getting Word documents with working links into our RaR corpus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the Doc Con (specifically the Microsoft Doc and Docx conversion) removes the *external* links. The *internal* links are preserved.

Unfortunately there is no configuration setting(s) to preserve the external links.